# TYPO3: Extensions in TemplaVoila template

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I've installed a Twitter plugin from the Typo3 repository.

What would be the best way to insert a "variable" into my TemplaVoila template so I can place the twitter feed on my template? (I want it to be visible on every page)

I imagined inserting something like ###TWITTER### into my TemplaVoila template which Typo3 would replace with the twitter feed, instead of adding the plugin to every page.

Answer (score 1):

You can map your tv template marker with templavoila like usually. Then in your typoscript template you can create a content object with this twitter plugin and add it to your page object. I'm not sure how templavoila can help you?

Here is an example of a TS Object Path in TV:

```
    <field_toolmenu type="array">
     <tx_templavoila type="array">
    <title>Toolmenu</title>
    <description>mappt Toolmenu</description>
    <sample_data type="array">
         <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
    </sample_data>
    <eType>TypoScriptObject</eType>
               <TypoScriptObjPath>lib.toolmenu</TypoScriptObjPath>
    </tx_templavoila>
</field_toolmenu>
```

lib.toolmenu is the obj path you can add a plugin or any ts content object (cObject) in your page template.

Comment: What is a template marker and content object? How do I map it? I'm new to Typo3.

Comment: @Simon: Basically it's what Fedir said: TypoScript Objects Path with TemplaVoila. Template marker = HTML template / TV template

Comment: Okay, so Template Marker is my HTML file I imported into TemplaVoila?

Comment: @Simon When you create a template with TemplaVoila it is possible to define fields and to map them visually to elements in an html file. This mapping is what makes it possible to insert content on page generation.

Answer (score 1):

Use TypoScript Objects Path with TemplaVoiila.

You could define a TypoScript object lib.twitter which will contain Your plugin, and to map it after into TemplaVoila with BE module interface.

Comment: What is "TypoScript Objects Path" and "BE Module Interface"?

Comment: It's kind of type of content object, which You could use, when You map Your template with TV.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I don't understand a lot of it. Do you know where there's some documentation that explains "Objects Path", "BE Module Interface", "Content Objects"?

Comment: TV manuals. There is some videos on the network : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lcmEZi5jXg